# R, gglagplot, latex, no points on plot in final pdf

Tags: r, latex, ggfortify

My goal is to include a gglagplot into a latex file. Here is the code for creating the plot in R:

```
# create a lagplot and save it in a pdf named "lagplot"

set.seed(1)
data<-rnorm(100)
gglagplot(data,lags=9)
ggsave(file="lagplot.pdf")
dev.off()
```

Here is how I included the plot in latex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

lag plot without points:

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{lagplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In RStudio the plot looks as intended, however, on my final pdf created with the above latex code all data points on the plot have simply vanished. All I can see is 9 empty facets. 
When I export the graph with RStudio via "export" and "save as pdf", it works perfectly. Please help me!

Comment: Try enveloping the `gglagplot` between `pdf()` and `dev.off()`. FWIW, you don't need a `dev.off()` when plotting with `ggsave`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help! Any further ideas?

Comment: Do your lag plot look as intended in the file lag plot.pdf? I have repeated your example above and it works well for me in Latex.

Comment: yes, lagplot.pdf looks as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with Latex/your tex compiler rather than `gglagplot`, where the former doesn't display some layers of the `lagplot.pdf`.

I have repeated your example above yielding the following working result:

[image]

Try any of the following measures for redeeming your problem:

- Export the image as `.eps` rather than `.pdf` from RStudio:

  ```
  `ggsave(file = "lagplot.eps")`
  ```
- If you haven't already, try to us the `pdflatex` compiler. From your shell (assuming you are in directory of your latex file):

  ```
  > pdflatex myLatexFile.tex
  ```

Hopefully one of the above (or both combined) works.

Comment: saving the plot as an eps file worked for me, thank you!